# Why doesn't background-size work?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting `background-size: cover;` to work from my CSS file when specifying an inline background image via `style=""` tag:

CSS

```
header.hero {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 390px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-size: cover;
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<header class="hero" style="background-image: url('hero.jpeg');"></header>
```

If I add `!important` to `background-size: cover;`, it works properly. Why can I not get this to work without `!important`?

Comment: Is there other CSS being applied to the element? Also change `background:  #cccccc;` to `background-color: #cccccc` as you're using the longform for all other properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing `background: #cccccc;` to `background-color: #cccccc;`.

As `background` is a shorthand rule, it will override some the of values you set earlier.

Initial value, as each of the properties of the shorthand:

```
background-image: none
background-position: 0% 0%
background-size: auto auto
background-repeat: repeat
background-origin: padding-box
background-clip: border-box
background-attachment: scroll
background-color: transparent
```

Answer (score 1):

You are **overwritting** all your background styles with `background: #cccccc;` because you are not specifiyng the background attribute, so you should change it by

`background-color: #cccccc;`

by this way the background color will work as color attribute and won't overwrite the others attributes